# Does string contain an Item in a list, and get that index

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to work something out,  I have a string, and a list

```
string mystring = "this is my string";
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

int i = 0;

mylist.Add("yes");
mylist.Add("no");
mylist.Add("my");
mylist.Add("foobar");
```

I want to know does `mystring` contain (anywhere) an item in the `mylist` and which item (index) in `mylist` it is.  There will be no repeats in the list either.

so the result of `i` should be 2 in the case of this example.

I could easily do this with a loop, but I was hoping for an easier "one liner" if you will.

Comment: What should happen if more than one item of the list is in the string?

Comment: I will have already removed duplicates

Comment: Will the list only contain single words, or can it contain something like "is my"?  Should it only match on complete words, for instance if the list contained "hi" would that match because "this" contains "hi"?

Comment: Only be single words, no spaces at least.  I am looking for an exact match as well.

Comment: @Angryjames, even if there are no duplicates in the list, you might have `"this"` and `"is"`. Should it return `0`, `1` or what?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one line by using the overload of `Select` that includes the index:

```
string mystring = "this is my string";
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

mylist.Add("yes");
mylist.Add("no");
mylist.Add("my");
mylist.Add("foobar");

var result = mylist.Select((s,i) => new {s, i})
                   .Where(si => mystring.Contains(si.s));
```

yields:

```
(1 item) 

s    i
---- ----
my   2
```

Comment: `ver` should be `var` (can't do single-char edit).  Otherwise, very nice.

Comment: @MarcL. Thanks, fixed (and removed `.Dump()`)

Answer (score 2):

```
var indexes = mystring.Split()
                      .Where(w => mylist.Contains(w))
                      .Select(w => mylist.IndexOf(w))
                      .ToList();
```

you can't use a single `int i` as your list can contain 0+ words, so use an array or a `List`.

Comment: @Pluc `If the separatorargument is null or contains no characters, the method treats white-space characters as the delimiters` per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well, I learned something new.  Didn't realize by leaving it empty it would do that for white space, I've been always doing `' '`.  Thank you for the documentation on that.

Comment: @Greg sure thing.  One of those things that is not immediately obvious - I didn't know for a long time.

Comment: Well, it doesn't help that most people do `' '`.  Plus Visual Studio always loads the char parameter input also.  So it would definitely be an easy miss, but great thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = mylist.IndexOf(mylist.FirstOrDefault(s => Regex.IsMatch(mystring, string.Format("(^| ){0}( |$)", s))));
```

This will give you the index of the first word in the list that appears in the string